# How to use multiple input in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker

Here is my html code , for second input type there is not a icon, where is my error?
Thanks.

```
  <div>
        <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
            <label> Start : </label> <input type="text" value="" name="date1"></input>
            <span class="add-on"> <i data-time-icon="icon-time"
                data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
            <label> End : </label> <input type="text" value="" name="date2"></input>
            <span class="add-on"> <i data-time-icon="icon-time"
                data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format : 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: use diffrent id for second input containing `div`; then use that id in the javascript too. i.e. `$('#datetimepicker, #<2nd datepicker id>').datetimepicker(...`

Comment: That could be a css issue.

Comment: input tags doesn't have closing tag `<input type="text"/>`

Comment: Thanks for all responses, @mshsayem it's worked thank you again

Answer (score 1):

ID's *must* be unique - give them all the same class instead, e.g `datetimepicker`:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format : 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
});
```